# multiple command name

Tags: spring, jsp

How to declare multiple commandName in JSP? Normal example (one command name):

```
<form:form method="post" action="saveContact.do" commandName="newContact">
```

I want:

```
<form:form method="post" action="saveContact.do" commandName="newContact" commandName="newAdress">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make a Pojo with `newContact` which contains `newAdress`.

```
public class Contact{    
Address adress;    

getAddress(){
    return address
}

setAddress(Address address){
     this.address=address;
}
```

Fix the form to work in this way and all work well.

```
<form:form method="post" action="saveContact.do" commandName="newContact">
     <form:input name="address.street" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed to have only one object per form, you can create another class with fields newContact and newAdress.